Integration of $\int\frac{1}{x(x-1)\sqrt{x^2+4x+1}}\,dx$

Evaluation of

$\displaystyle I =\int\frac{1}{x(x-1)\sqrt{x^2+4x+1}}dx$
What I try : put
$\displaystyle \sqrt{x^2+4x+1}=(t+x)$
$\displaystyle x^2+4x+1=x^2+t^2+2tx$
$\displaystyle x=\frac{1-t^2}{4-2t}$ and $\displaystyle dx=\frac{t^2-4t+1}{2(2-t)^2}\,dt$
So $\displaystyle I =2\int \frac{t^2-4t+1}{(1-t^2)(2t-t^2-3)(4t-3t^2+1)}\,dt$
I did not understand How can I solve less Complex way
Please have a look on that problem, Thanks

Isn't $x=\frac{1-t^2}{2t-4}$?

If you want to continue from the place where you stopped, then you can take the numerator as a linear combinations of the quadratic polynomials in denominator.... but that would be really long... as you will have to partially decompose from there again. Else @Riemann's answer works well...

Note that
$$\frac1{x(x-1)}=\frac1{x-1}-\frac1x,$$
then
$$I=\int\frac{\text{d}x}{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2+4x+1}}
-\int\frac{\text{d}x}{x\sqrt{x^2+4x+1}}
=I_1-I_2.$$
For $I_1$, you can make $u=\frac{1}{x-1}$; and for $I_2$, you can make $v=\frac1x$.
I think those will make your computation easier.

There is an error in your computation of the Euler substitution. You should instead obtain
\begin{align}
&\int\frac{1}{x(x-1)\sqrt{x^2+4x+1}}dx\\
=& \int \frac{4(2-t)}{(t^2-1)(t^2+2t-5)}dt
=\int \frac{2}{t^2+2t-5}-\frac{2}{t^2-1}\ dt\\
= &\ \frac1{\sqrt6}\ln|\frac{t+1-\sqrt6}{t+1+\sqrt6}|+\ln|\frac{t-1}{t+1}|+C
\end{align}
